# Solve the equation $\sqrt{x^2-3x+18}+\sqrt{x^2+5x+2} = 2\sqrt{x^4+2x^3+5x^2+84x+36}.$

Tags: real-numbers

Solve the equation $$\sqrt{x^2-3x+18}+\sqrt{x^2+5x+2} = 2\sqrt{x^4+2x^3+5x^2+84x+36}.$$
I don't know where to start, but what I know is that
$$(x^2-3x+18)(x^2+5x+2) = x^4+2x^3+5x^2+84x+36.$$
Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: @AnotherUser don’t you think the context is enough? The OP has made a key observation wrt factoring the quartic polynomial

Comment: I'll give you a hint. I think you already know about this, but $(x^2-3x+18)(x^2+5x+2)=x^4+2x^3+5x^2+84x+36$. So, let $\sqrt{x^2-3x+18}=A, \sqrt{x^2+5x+2}=B$. So, $A+B=2AB.$ You may start from here.

Comment: @wasn'tme it's not $(a+b)/2 = \sqrt{ab}$, it's $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} = 2\sqrt{ab}$

Comment: @wasn'tme It is, $(a+b)/2=ab$.

Comment: @RDK ok, lemme try a sec

Comment: @RDK still don't figure it out, can you give me more hint T0T

Comment: Alright, second hint. $2A+2B=4AB, 4AB-2A-2B=0.$ Try adding some numbers to both sides, and make this to $(\square)(\square)=\square$.

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137544/discussion-between-rdk-and-longirsu).

Comment: Still didn't figure it out, any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Problem leads to 8th degree equation with integer coefficients. I suppose there is no closed-form solution.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu TvT